# Error : Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, imageicon

Trato de cargar una imagen, ya intenté de muchas formas, usando la carpeta `images/imagenes/iconos/icons`, pero no me abre la imagen, estoy usando Apache Netbeans 12.4

```
fondo = this.getClass().getResource("/source/dceit_logo.png");
imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(fondo).getImage();
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que indicas:

> Error : Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because
> "location" is null

se debe simplemente a que el nombre o la ruta del archivo es incorrecta.

De acuerdo a tu código debes tener  dentro del directorio "src" un  directorio llamado "source" que contiene la imagen "dceit_logo.png"

```
src/
├── source/
│    └── dceit_logo.png
```

De esta forma cargarías la imagen

```
imagenFondo = new ImageIcon("source/dceit_logo.png");
```