# Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, combobox, icono

Estoy intentando usar un combobox para hacer que al elegir una opción se cambie de imagen, por lo que estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
private void cboSeleccionItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                              
    int img=cboSeleccion.getSelectedIndex();
    switch(img){
        case 1 -> {
            ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/download.jpg"));
            lblImagen.setIcon(imagen);
        }
        case 2 -> {
            ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/download_1.jpg"));
            lblImagen.setIcon(imagen);
        }
        case 3 -> {
            ImageIcon imagen  = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/images.jpg"));
            lblImagen.setIcon(imagen);
        }
    }
}
```

El programa se ejecuta sin problemas pero no sale la imagen al momento de cambiar entre las opciones. Soy principiante en esto por lo que no sé que estoy haciendo mal.
Adjunto una imagen de mi paquete jar. Uso Apache NetBeans IDE 16

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las imágenes se encuentran en el path correcto, podrías agregar tu clase?, tal vez lblImagen no tiene visibilidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys las rutas que inician con diagonal se toman como desde el directorio raíz, seguramente ese es el problema, además de que si usa maven debería de usar la estructura de directorios estándard de maven para delegar la configuración de los antes mencionados en los procesos de configuración, empaquetamiento y despliegue mediante el maven_resources_plugin

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error : Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/484278/error-cannot-invoke-java-net-url-toexternalform-because-location-is-null)

Comment: @RuslanLópez ya veo "/"!, puedes agregar una respuesta, solo las respuestas aceptadas pueden considerarse para cerrar otras duplicadas.

Comment: Hola @Joao, estoy casi seguro que el error está en **this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/download_1.jpg")**, el this está de más, quítalo y debería funcionar, Ruslan López, no es así, lo que está tomando es la ruta relativa al archivo, que parte de **src**, entonces si tienes una carpeta **imagenes** dentro de **src**, debes referenciarla com **"/imagenes/archivo.arc"**.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve un problema similar, y se debía a que tenía que poner "./imagenes/...".
A mi compañero que tenía un mac sí que le leía bien el path al iniciar con barra, pero en mi caso (Windows) tenía que poner un punto delante.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).